# Speed of light in vacuum observed by a moving observer

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

Suppose I and a person, moving with a speed $v$ with respect to me, observe a ray of light passing through points A and B.

I observe the length between A and B to be $L_0$ and time that it took for light to cover it to be $t_0$.

Using time dilation and length contraction formulae, we find that the other person observed these to be $t=\frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ and $L=L_0(\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}})$.

So the other person observes light speed to be $\frac{L}{t}=\frac{L_0(\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}))}{\frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}}=\frac{L_0}{t_0}(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})$. This is different from the light speed measured by me which is $\frac{L_0}{t_0}$.

So what mistake am I doing since both must measure the same light speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first mistake is to use length contraction and time dilation formulas, ignoring simultaneity (you need to use the full Lorentz Transform to solve these problems).  I call this "gamma slinging", because it *trivializes* the whole idea of Special Relativity.  You cannot just plug gamma in to non-relativistic equations and expect things to work.  This is the main mistake made by more than 99% of posters here.

Your second & more minor mistake, is to attempt to use these formulas to calculate the speed of light, because the formulas were derived assuming the constant value of c in the first place.

Comment: *Your second & more minor mistake, is to attempt to use these formulas to calculate the speed of light, because the formulas were derived assuming the constant value of c in the first place.* How is that a mistake? Both observers should see the same distance per time traveled by the light.

Comment: It just means that, even when you get the right answer you are not really checking anything, as constant c is built into the Lorentz Transform.  Minor as I said, but worth knowing.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I was just thrown off by your use of the word "mistake".

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that, given the time you measure is $t_{0}$, the time the moving observer measures is actually $t=t_{0}/\gamma$ with $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$. You might have mixed up the frames in your definition. Together with $L=L_{0}/\gamma$ you have $$L/t = L_{0}/t_{0}$$

Comment: The formula I've read is $t=\gamma t_0$ where $t_0$ is proper time. It can be seen here https://www.phy.olemiss.edu/HEP/QuarkNet/time.html

Comment: As it states on your reference, the clocks of moving observers "run slower" compared to stationary clocks meaning that if you were to look into their spaceship with a powerful telescope you would see their ticks running slower (all other effects neglected). We can therefore expect $t\leq t_{0}$ since fewer ticks have occured and $\gamma$ just gets really big when $v$ approaches $c$. I guess the problem is again in the definition of the frame, not sure though :)

Comment: But that $t$ is what I observed to be the time measured by moving observer's frame. What did he observe while sitting in his frame? For him, his $t$ would've been larger than my $t_0$ as I'm moving wrt him.